# Converting coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a point in $\mathbb{C}$ (and back again)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, complex

I have a list of control points for a BezierFunction. I want to apply a function taking input a complex number to these points and then plot the BezierFunction of the resulting points. I'm looking for a way to convert a list of points in the form $\{a,b\}$ to the form $a+bi$. After applying my function and obtaining the resulting list of points in this complex number form I would like to convert this back to a list of points in the original form.

Comment: Look up [`Complex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complex.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 10000;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
ToComplex[x_] := x.{1, I};

(*to complex numbers*)
z = ToComplex[x];
(*to real vectors*)
y = ReIm[z];
```

As to answer to MarcoB's comment: Of course applying `Complex` does work but it is slower (be a factor of almosr 20) because it is not vectorized:

```
n = 1000000;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
z1 = ToComplex[x]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
z2 = Complex @@@ x; // AbsoluteTiming // First
z1 == z2
```

> 0.022322
>
> 0.424101
>
> True

Comment: For the conversion to complex number, wouldn’t `Complex @@ list` work?

Comment: @MarcoB Oh, good point! Of course one can do that. It is just slower (see edit). ;)